# How to mock a MongoDB collection of type IMongoCollection<T> to return some predefined data?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

Below is my code:

**Controller/Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(CustomerViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    try
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        // when debugging the test, _dbContext.Customers throws exception
        CustomerDoc existingCustomer = await _dbContext.Customers.Find(o => o.email == model.email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (existingCustomer != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "email already used.");
        }
        // other checkings 

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // if model state is valid, do something here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**And my unit test code is:**

```
[Fact]
public async Task should_return_view_with_errors_when_email_already_exists()
{
    IEnumerable<CustomerDoc> customers = new List<CustomerDoc>
    {
        new CustomerDoc
        {
            email = "test@test.com"
        }
    };

    _dbContextMock.SetupAllProperties();

    // below line is causing the error
    _dbContextMock.Setup(c => c.Customers).Returns(() =>(IMongoCollection<CustomerDoc>)customers);

    CustomerViewModel model = new CustomerViewModel
    {
        email = "test@test.com"
    };

    CreateController();

    var result = await _controller.Register(model);

    Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
    Assert.False(_controller.ModelState.IsValid);
    Assert.True(_controller.ModelState.ContainsKey("Email"));
}
```

As you can see in my unit test code comment, I am trying to mock a IMongoCollection to return some data. But I am not able to do so because **_dbContext.Customers** is throwing exception.

How can I mock **IMongoCollection** to return some predefined data?

**I am using**
asp.net core 2.1.0
mongodb driver 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You declare `customers` as a `List`:

```
IEnumerable<CustomerDoc> customers = new List<CustomerDoc>
```

but then try to cast it to `IMongoCollection`

```
() =>(IMongoCollection<CustomerDoc>)customers
```

There's two immediate directions (but both have further issues to deal with):

1) Just return the list without the cast

```
() => customers
```

but I can't see the type of `c.Customers` so I suspect this will just move the issue. I'll take a guess that it's `IMongoCollection<CustomerDoc>` which is why you're trying to do the cast in the first place? This is problematic as the `.Returns` would need to be be associated with a function performing the equivalent of `c.Customer.Find()`. Even so, it's probably better than the alternative.

2) Changing the `customers` variable to a type that implements `IMongoCollection`.

Option 1 feels like the way to go as option 2 forces you to start dealing with lots of logic that really shouldn't be relevant to this piece of code.